# How to add base url in my link

Tags: magento2.4.1

How to add my base URL instead of **http://localhost/m2**

```
if (data.productid == 'false') {
    window.location.replace("http://localhost/m2/customer/account/login");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using BASE_URL

I believe that this is there on every page of Magento 2

```
if (data.productid == 'false') {
    window.location.replace(BASE_URL + "customer/account/login");
}
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the website url in JS you can use this with requirejs.

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/url'
], function ($,url) { 

  var linkUrl = url.build('customer/account/login');
  console.log(linkUrl);
});
```

Comment: I am getting confused, can u pls help me how to add in my code : https://codeshare.io/5NwPp1

Comment: Sure, where is your code ? In <script> tags in a phtml or in a js file ?

Comment: <script> tags in a phtml

Comment: I have filled the codeshare, can you check ?

Comment: sure, let me check

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the base url into the JS if it is a component or the simple and lazy way would be use something like the example below.

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;

var host = window.location.host;
```